# How to customize a new colour theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, numix

In gnome-shell, I have changed the theme to `Numix`. 
But, in Transmission, the progress bar is now invisible:

[image]

I would like to change some colours in the theme configuration to be able to see that progress bar. I have seen that this is reported as a bug, but is there any way to fix it myself?

Comment: https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme/issues/297 - It was unfixed as of 29th of Feb, and he assigned a dev to fix it on 12 March. I just bumped the thread - let's see if anything happens!

Answer (score 0):

The Transmission issue got fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme/commit/dae4da6b7cf6d13ecced503db61531abb5509861)

Comment: May be, the version in Ubuntu is not up to date.

Comment: Install it from Numix PPA: https://launchpad.net/~numix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa